# react native redux storing state across multiple pages

Tags: react-native, redux

trying to learn redux and having issues passing state around to keep a user up to date, main example - create a user on page 1, navigate to page 2, set something on the user and navigate back to page 1.

having to create an action for page2 navigated passing the user and also creating an action for page 1 navigated passing the user back and forth.

what is the correct usage of redux?

1. user must be passed back and forth to keep app sync

   ```
   { 
   page1: user: {...data}} set user details,
   page2: user: {...data}} passed user details but able to edit user 
    details and able to go back to page1
   }
   ```
2. user can be accessed globally at any time and updated with action calls

   ```
   {
    userDetails: {user: {...data}},
    page1: only page specific state, accesses this.props.userDetails.user
    page2: only page specific state, accesses this.props.userDetails.user
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So normally you'd just subscribe whatever component needed user information to the Redux store, typically with `react-redux`. In `page2` you'd dispatch an action to modify the user in the store, then when the reducer processes those modifications, `page1` can update with the new value.

An action for mutating the user might look like this:

```
{
  type: 'SET_USER_EMAIL',
  email: 'foo@wombat.com'
}
```

You'd `dispatch` that action from your `page2` component. It'd be received in the reducer for the `user` object in the store:

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'SET_USER_EMAIL':
    return {
      ...state,
      email: action.email
    }
}
```

If both pages are subscribed to the Redux store, there's not really a "passing back and forth" of the user value so much as both pages are notified when the store changes, and can update themselves based on those changes. I guess you'd say that each component *listens* to the store and can take action when it updates.

Navigation is a somewhat separate issue, though it certainly can use Redux. I feel like possibly you might benefit from revisiting some of the [core concepts](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/) to make things clearer.